# division of array on some criterion

Tags: c++

in this code i try to divide  the  a[5] into two arrays on the criterion of stored data in the array ....... 
and store the index of the array a[5] to other arrays to show these index contain different data elements 
but i doesn't work for me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printarray(int b[], int count)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        cout<<b[i]<<endl;
}

void main()
{
    int a[5]={1,0,0,1,1};
    int array[5][5]=
    {
        {0,5,0,4,0},
        {0,0,6,0,7},
        {0,0,0,0,8},
        {0,0,0,0,10},
        {0,0,0,0,0}
    };

    int count=0;
    int counti=0;
    int C1=0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(C1==a[i])
        {
            count++;
        }

        else
        {
            counti++;
        }
    }

    int *b= new int[count];
    int *c= new int[counti];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        if(C1==a[i])
        {
            b[i]=i;
        }
        else
        {
            c[i]=i;
        }
    }

    printarray(b,count);
}
```

the code display the grabage values... plz help me 
its show the following result
-842151450 
1

Comment: Probably a good starting point to learn how to use the debugger, to step through your program line by line.

Comment: And learn how to indent code, particularly when asking people to look at it. And `main` must return an `int`

Comment: Using `i` in your `b[i] = ` and `c[i] = ` isn't going to cut it. they need their own independent indexes. And you realize `array` isn't used in any of this code *at all*, right?

Comment: You definitely should use `delete []` on `b` and `c` as soon as you're done with the allocated memories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first i was 1 , so b will contain {1, 2}. where ( b[1] = 1, b[2] = 2 )
when you loop through b to print all elements you start from index 0 although b started from index 1.

you can fix index using (j, k instead of i).

```
int *b = new int[count];
int *c = new int[counti];
int j, k;
j = k = 0;

for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{

    if (C1 == a[i])
    {
        b[j++] = i;         
    }
    else
    {
        c[k++] = i;
    }
}
printarray(b, count);
```